# Telerik Grid not styling properly when scrolling horizontal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using MVC-3 design pattern in C# with Razor and Telerik Grid controls. All great execpt for one minor problem which will prevent us releasing the product.

We are just using the standard telerik styles, so no custom CSS. However, as expected, it all looks quite nice until... You scroll horizontally right.

Before scrolling:
[image]

After scrolling:
[image]

The telerik control itself doesnt actually seem to support horizontal scrolling so we popped a div tag around it and set the scroll bar on that. Even using the Telerik window control the same thing happens. Telerik does support vertical scrolling, and setting the .Scrollable() activates that. Is there a way to say something like .Scrollable("Horizontal") or something.

From my guess, it seems to be something to do with the header and footer not expanding to contain all the columns. Is there any way I can fix it. I have tried over the last day or so digging around in the telerik style sheets and JQuery but to no avail.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Edit 1: As one of the answers below pointed out, I should add .Width(xxx) to every column and it will work. I did do this before but it did not work. Apologies for not saying this before now.

Edit 2: The code as requested:

```
<div id="ListContent">
    @{
        Html.Telerik()
            .Grid<YeatsClinical.PatientPortal.Web.ViewModels.PatientEducation>("PatientEducations")
            .Name("grid")
            .DataKeys(k => k.Add(o => o.MrPatientEducationId))

            .Columns(c =>
                {
                    c.Bound(o => o.MrPatientEducationId).ReadOnly().Width(100);
                    c.Command(s =>
                    {
                        s.Select();
                    }).Width(100);
                    c.Bound(o => o.PatientId).Visible(false).Width(100);
                    c.Bound(o => o.MrPatientEncounterId).Visible(false).Width(100);
                    c.Bound(o => o.MrPatientEducationResourceId).Visible(false).Width(100);
                    c.Bound(o => o.GivenAsPrint).Width(100);
                    c.Bound(o => o.DatePrinted).Width(100);
                    c.Bound(o => o.SentViaEmail).Width(100);
                    c.Bound(o => o.DocumentTitle).Width(100);
                    // image is temporary disabled because its causing huge lag spikes and very long database retrievals
                    c.Bound(o => o.File).Visible(false).Width(100);
                    c.Bound(o => o.DateCreated).Width(100);
                    c.Bound(o => o.CreatedByUserId).Visible(false).Width(100);
                    c.Bound(o => o.DateLastUpdated).Width(100);
                    c.Bound(o => o.LastUpdatedByUserId).Visible(false).Width(100);
                })
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
            .Filterable()
            .Groupable()
            .Render();
    }
</div>
```

The outer div above is the one styled with the blue scrollbar.

Comment: Why are people marking the question down without even explaining in a comment their reason or offering a suggestion on how to improve it.

Comment: Can you post your code for the grid (the html.Telerik stuff)?

Comment: What happens when you add .Scrollable() to the method string at the bottom?  You mentioned you tried it to no avail in another comment, but did you get an error, or did the grid simply not change at all with the addition?

Comment: I got a vertical scrollbar, but no horizontal one.

Comment: I'm stumped then, sorry.  I have lots of telerik grids in one of my projects, and they all scroll horz and vert with no problem, as long as the column widths are set.  Otherwise the columns just collapse into the available space.  Sometimes telerik is picky and tough (if not impossible) to debug.  One thing that has helped me in the past is stripping the control down to the bare minimum.  Then add one thing at a time to try to see where it's breaking or conflicting.  Sorry I couldn't be more helpful--Good luck!

Comment: No problem Jeff. I will take your advice and try it out. Thanks for all your help so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, Thanks to both Jeff and Pollirrata who both helped in finding partial answers to the question. However after a bit more research I found the answer elsewhere. But I decided to post a link here for others who may have the same problem.

On reading the telerik manual as pointed out by pollirrata, I do need to add .Width to ALL the columns **(Step 1)** and aslo add Scrollable()**(Step 2)**. While I did do this before, it did not work because of the reasons explained below, however +1 to pollirata for his helpful answer as this needs to be done.

Thanks also to Jeff who offered help by suggesting likewise in his comments, I cant +1 the answer as I have taken .Pageable away and it made no difference, and as explained, when I added the code as he posted, I got an execption. However, I can +1 the comments, unfortunately, while his comments were correct, the answer provided by him is not).

Since I started the post I came across [this link](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/horizontal-scrolling-and-the-grid-header.aspx) and noted that the version of jQuery I was using was 1.5 and Telerik needed V1.7.1. I have since updated my version and this partially helped solve the problem **(Step 3)**. I also checked and double checked the other dependancies that the link refrences and have all of them were as required. However, I did note that one of the sub dependancies were missing. In my case, my grid required DatePicker - which I had, but DatePicker required Calender - which I did not have (must have deleted it by accident) **(Step 4)**. I have also ensured that I am had the correct refrences for using the .Compressed() and .Combined() methods throughout the project as refred to in the second link. After this final step, all went well **(Step 5)**.

Thanks everyone for your help and guidance on this.

Answer (score 1):

Telerik MVC Grid do support Horizontal scrolling. Just set the width for all your columns and add .`Scrollable()` to the Grid and that's it

Comment: While this seems somewhat cumbersome, I have already tried it but to no avail. Sorry, I guess I should have pointed that out in the question so I will do an edit. However, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Please Use the following technique**

```
<div class="DataGridXScroll">
    @(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("grvSalesSummary")
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(k => k.Unit_Code))
    .Columns(column =>
    {
        column.Bound(s => s.Zone_Name).Width(100).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "GridColumnLeftAlign" }).Hidden(true)
            .GroupHeaderTemplate(@<text>Zone: @item.Key</text>);
        column.Bound(s => s.Region_Name).Width(100).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "GridColumnLeftAlign" }).Hidden(true)
            .GroupHeaderTemplate(@<text>Region: @item.Key</text>);
        column.Bound(s => s.Unit_Code).Width(100).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "GridColumnLeftAlign" });
        column.Bound(s => s.Unit_Name).Width(150).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "GridColumnLeftAlign" });

        column.Bound(s => s.TotalCustomer).Width(70).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "GridColumnRightAlign" })
             .Aggregate(aggreages => aggreages.Sum())
                .Format("{0:N}")
                .FooterTemplate(@<text> @item.Sum.Format("{0:N}") </text>)
                .GroupFooterTemplate(@<text>@item.Sum.Format("{0:N}")</text>);

        column.Bound(s => s.TotalActiveCustomer).Width(70).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "GridColumnRightAlign" })
             .Aggregate(aggreages => aggreages.Sum())
                .Format("{0:N}")
                .FooterTemplate(@<text> @item.Sum.Format("{0:N}") </text>)
                .GroupFooterTemplate(@<text>@item.Sum.Format("{0:N}")</text>);

        column.Bound(s => s.NoOfSalesInCurrentMonth).Width(70).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "GridColumnRightAlign" })
             .Aggregate(aggreages => aggreages.Sum())
                .Format("{0:N}")
                .FooterTemplate(@<text> @item.Sum.Format("{0:N}") </text>)
                .GroupFooterTemplate(@<text>@item.Sum.Format("{0:N}")</text>);

        column.Bound(s => s.TotalRecoveredWithoutDP).Width(100).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "GridColumnRightAlign" })
             .Aggregate(aggreages => aggreages.Sum())
                .Format("{0:N}")
                .FooterTemplate(@<text> @item.Sum.Format("{0:N}") </text>)
                .GroupFooterTemplate(@<text>@item.Sum.Format("{0:N}")</text>);

        column.Bound(s => s.CollectionInCurrentMonth).Width(100).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "GridColumnRightAlign" })
             .Aggregate(aggreages => aggreages.Sum())
                .Format("{0:N}")
                .FooterTemplate(@<text> @item.Sum.Format("{0:N}") </text>)
                .GroupFooterTemplate(@<text>@item.Sum.Format("{0:N}")</text>);

        column.Bound(s => s.TotalOverdue).Width(70).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "GridColumnRightAlign" })
             .Aggregate(aggreages => aggreages.Sum())
                .Format("{0:N}")
                .FooterTemplate(@<text> @item.Sum.Format("{0:N}") </text>)
                .GroupFooterTemplate(@<text>@item.Sum.Format("{0:N}")</text>);

        column.Bound(s => s.TotalAdvance).Width(70).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "GridColumnRightAlign" }) .Aggregate(aggreages => aggreages.Sum())
                .Format("{0:N}")
                .FooterTemplate(@<text> @item.Sum.Format("{0:N}") </text>)
                .GroupFooterTemplate(@<text>@item.Sum.Format("{0:N}")</text>);

        column.Bound(s => s.TotalOutstanding).Width(80).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "GridColumnRightAlign" })
             .Aggregate(aggreages => aggreages.Sum())
                .Format("{0:N}")
                .FooterTemplate(@<text> @item.Sum.Format("{0:N}") </text>)
                .GroupFooterTemplate(@<text>@item.Sum.Format("{0:N}")</text>);

        column.Template(@<a href="http://172.25.40.50/MonthlyEntrySales/SalesReports.aspx?lc=@item.Unit_Code" target="_blank">Show</a>).Width(50);

        column.Bound(s => s.FinalizedByRM).Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}").Width(90).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "GridColumnLeftAlign" });
        column.Bound(s => s.FinalizedByZM).Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}").Width(90).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "GridColumnLeftAlign" });
        column.Bound(s => s.FinalizedByHO).Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}").Width(90).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "GridColumnLeftAlign" });

        column.Template(@<a href="#" onclick="return SaveSalesStatus('@item.Unit_Code','@item.FinalizedByRM','@item.FinalizedByZM','@item.FinalizedByHO');">Save</a>).Width(50);
    })
    .Selectable()
    .Scrollable(scroll => scroll.Height(300))
    .Groupable(settings => settings.Groups(group =>
    {
        group.Add(g => g.Zone_Name);
        group.Add(g => g.Region_Name);

    }).Visible(false))
    )
</div>
```

**Add the following CSS**

```
.DataGridXScroll
{
    width: 1000px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    text-align: left;
}
```